# error "Input z must be 2D, not 3D" related to plot nc file in python

Tags: multidimensional-array, raster, netcdf, contourf

I used 500 hPa NOAA Reanalysis Version 3 to plot the mean anomaly of vertical velocity during a specific period (https://www.psl.noaa.gov/mddb2/makePlot.html?variableID=142267). I got the "input z must be 2D, not 3D" error when the following code was used:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,9), constrained_layout=True ) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111).set_title('b1' , size=10 , fontweight='bold') #(nrow , ncol ,nfig)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0 )
nc1 = NetCDFFile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/nc2024Habib/final-mjo/obs1-vv-ac.nc')
lat = nc1.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc1.variables['lon'][:]
#z=nc1.variables['level'][0]
omega = nc1.variables['omega'][:]
map= Basemap    (projection='merc',llcrnrlon=0.,llcrnrlat=10.,urcrnrlon=80.,urcrnrlat=45.,resolution='i',fix_aspect=False)  
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawlsmask(land_color='Linen', ocean_color='#CCFFFF')
map.drawcounties() 
parallels = np.arange(15.,45.,5.)
meridians = np.arange(30.,70.,5.)
map.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10 , linewidth=0.9,dashes=[4,9900], fontweight='bold' ,fontstyle='oblique')
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10, linewidth=0.9,dashes=[4,9900] , fontweight='bold', fontstyle='oblique')
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon-180,lat )
X,Y = map(lons,lats)
clevs1 = np.arange(-0.02,0.01,0.005)
cs1 = map.contourf(X,Y, omega[0,:,:],clevs1,cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.show()
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Print `omega[0,:,:].ndim` or `omega[0,:,:].shape`; It is going to be a 3-dimensional array (as the error says), while you should pass a 2D array to `contourf()`.

I just checked; `omega` has dimensions `(time, level, lat, lon)`, so you have to slice off one more dimension using e.g.:

```
cs1 = map.contourf(X, Y, omega[0,0,:,:], clevs1, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

To plot the first time step and first height level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used suggested solution but created just an empty map:

Comment: I mean, the omega variable was not drawn on the map

Comment: And what if you take some steps back, forget about `basemap` (which I always found a nightmare to work with, `cartopy` is a huge improvement in my opinion), and just plot the data with `plt.figure();plt.contourf(lon, lat, omega[0,0,:,:])`?

Comment: I plot the data with plt.contourf(lon, lat, omega[0,0,:,:]) . but created just an empty map

Comment: This problem is no longer related to the original question. If my answer solved that problem, please accept the answer. If you need more help with this problem, you will have to post a new question.